# npm run fails for some reason

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, office-js, npm-scripts, word-addins

Why would the following command fail?

```
npm run "start:desktop -- --app word"
```

says:

> npm ERR! Missing script: "start:desktop -- --app word"

I have ensured that `start:desktop` script exists in `scripts` section of `package.json`. If I remove the arguments part, it runs okay, so there is something I need to do with the `-- --app word` part.

Note: This need to be run from `launch.json`, but I was trying to run it directly in the console to see what was failing.

If it matters, this is a Yeoman-based Office.js project.

### Edit

I understand that because of the use of double-quotes, `npm run` thinks that the entire value `start:desktop -- --app word` is the name of the script and therefore can't find it. The problem however is that this is being invoked as a task from my debug configuration (`launch.json`) and there is no way of separating the arguments from the script name there. Here is the task definition:

```
{
  "label": "Debug: Word Desktop",
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "start:desktop -- --app word",
  "presentation": {
    "clear": true,
    "panel": "dedicated",
  },
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I tell it where the name of script ends and the arguments begin. I thought those double-dashes served exactly that purpose, but apparently they don't.

Comment: Update: This appears to be a bug and VSCode guys are looking into it. I'll update this post once we know about a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since your command contains quotes, it is treating everything inside the quotes as a single argument.

There is a script called `start:desktop`, but there is no script called literally `start:desktop -- --app word`

Try:

```
npm run start:desktop -- --app word
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, but VSCode doesn't. As I said in the question, this is a task that needs to be executed from `launch.json` debug configuration. I have no way of skipping the quotes in that file because it is JSON and takes a string value. I'll update my post to show that entry.